# Do Degree Zero Pseudo-Differential Operators on a Manifold Send Smooth Functions to Smooth Functions?

Tags: complex-geometry, pseudo-differential-operators, functional-calculus

I'm not an analyst, so forgive me if what I'm asking is not suitable for Mathoverflow.
For convenience, let $X$ be a compact complex manifold, and $E$ a holomorphic vector bundle on $X$. Let $H$ be the Hilbert space of $L^2$-integrable sections of $E$ on $X$, and let $F$ be a degree zero pseudo-differential operator in $\mathfrak{B}(H)$. Then my question is whether $F$ maps smooth(or complex/real analytic) sections to the same class of functions? What if $F$ is a degree $-1$ pseudo-differential operator?

More specifically, I'm thinking about the case when $E$ is $\oplus _i \wedge ^{0,i} T^*X $ and $F$ is either $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+D^2}}$ or $\frac{D}{\sqrt{1+D^2}}$, where $D= \bar{\partial}^* + \bar{\partial}$, where $\bar{\partial}$ is the Dolbeault operator.

Any helpful comments and references to learn about this subject is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the symbol of the pseudodifferential operator is smooth away from the zero section of the cotangent bundle, then it *always* maps smooth function to smooth functions. The order tells you how it maps between $L^2$ Sobolev spaces. An operator of order $K$ is a bounded map from $W^{2,j+k}$ to $W^{2,j}$ for any $j$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Do you have a reference for why smoothness of symbol results in the p.d.operator to send smooth functions to themselves? Also, if the symbol is say, analytic, can I say the same thing?

So it seems in case of the Dolbeault operator, if I understand correctly, the symbol at $(x,\zeta)$ is $\frac{1}{ i \Vert \zeta \Vert }$, which is smooth when $\zeta \neq 0$.

Comment: One way to see it is that smooth functions is within the intersection of Sobolev spaces. So Deane Yang's comment just follow.

Comment: @YYY I'm sorry, but I don't see how that follows. Could you please explain some more?

Comment: @Kashayar: This is not trivial. See http://math.mit.edu/~rbm/18.157-F05-Chapter5.ps, or http://math.mit.edu/~rbm/iml90c2.ps, for example. Your manifold is compact, so the estimates are not difficult.

Comment: For the specific operators you mentioned, they do map smooth sections to smooth sections.

Answer (score 3):

As Deane Yang pointed out, in general, an elliptic operator of order $s$ maps $H^{k}\rightarrow H^{k-s}$ for functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. The pseudo-differential operator on a compact manifold is defined by patching over local coordinates. A smooth function over the whole compact manifold is of course smooth in the local coordinates as well. So a standard partition of unity argument is suffice. Since a smooth functions' derivatives are bounded on $M$, it is trivially inside every Sobolev space. Together this gives you the desired argument.

The argument is usually expressed in terms of wave front sets. A standard theorem in distribution theory asserts that if $P$ is an operator with Schwartz kernel $K\in D'(\mathbb{R}^{m}\times \mathbb{R}^{n})$, and $K$'s wavefront set is contained in
$$
\{\xi\not=0, \eta\not=0\}
$$
Then $P$ defines maps 
$$
P:C^{\infty}_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})\rightarrow C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})
$$
(see Friedlander and Joshi, for example)

In your case the Schwartz kernel of both operators can be explicitly written down and then the above theorem can be applied. But I am not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem at here. In general, the Fourier transform of a compactly supported function is a Schwartz function, and that of a compactly supported distribution is an analytic function. So I think analyticity should follow as well. But I do not have a proof over the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. In the analytic case, can we still work locally? The partition of unity argument no longer works there.

Comment: @Kashayar: I honestly do not know. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Kashayar: Not sure if this is relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/110410/how-does-the-lack-of-partitions-of-unity-affect-the-structure-of-analytic-holomo. I will spend some time look into it.

Comment: For the real and complex analytic questions, I think you need hyperfunctions as developed by Sato and Kashiwara.

Comment: @DeaneYang: I guess you meant something like this: http://www.math.harvard.edu/~siu/math212b/division_of_distribution.pdf. I never really had time to read it carefully in the past. I will take a look at it carefully in future, I am not sure if it is related.

Comment: I meant something like this (but I don’t know if it answers the question): https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195526508